# AutocompleteActivity Google Places API onActivityResult nothing happening

Tags: android

I followed this guide on implementing placesautocomplete

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete

I followed the intent one not the fragment. Nothing happens when I select a place. It just shows me this picture when I click on a place :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujCT6.png)

I tried implementing the fragment version but same thing. Nothing happens.

```
@OnClick(R.id.editText) void searchLocation() {
        List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);
        Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields).setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.ADDRESS).setCountry("PH").build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                displayLocationSettingsRequest(getApplicationContext());
                break;
            case AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                    LatLng latLng = place.getLatLng();
                    String address = place.getAddress();
                    if (getIntent().getIntExtra("switch", 0) == 0) {
                        returnIntent.putExtra("pickup", address);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("latlng", latLng);
                    } else {
                        returnIntent.putExtra("dropoff", address);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("latlng", latLng);
                    }
                    selectedAddress = address;
                    editText.setText(address);
                    location.setText(address);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                    Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    // The user canceled the operation.
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CANCELLED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
        }
    }
```

I am forced to cancel the operation as selecting a place doesnt do anything and so resultcode always returns RESULT_CANCELLED

Comment: I am confronting the same problem and have found no solution, either with the activity or the fragment alternative.